# Boundary conditions for the "entrance" point of a diffusion process

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X(t)|_{t\ge0}$ is a one-dimensional diffusion process defined on the interval $[0,1]$. The diffusion coefficient vanishes at both ends, but the drift coefficient is pushing the system into the interior of the interval.

For example: $$dX=2(1-X)-2X+\sqrt{X(1-X)}dB_t$$

If both boundary points are unattainable from the interior region (i.e., if you start from $x_0\in (0,1)$, the probability of reaching $0$ or $1$ is zero), can we impose that the transition density function $p(x,t|x_0,0)$ always equals zero on both ends, for any $t>0$, even if we start the process on the boundaries?